# RecyclerView onBindViewHolder called multiple times for one item

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have used the `RececlerView` with the `ViewHolder` pattern for a while now.
Im am implementing a custom `Adapter`.

Im am not searching for a specific bug help in my code.

I was just wondering, if it's normal, that the `onBindViewHolder` method is called multiple times (for the same item) while scrolling to the end of the list and scrolling back up. In this case `onBindViewHolder` is called again for item 0 and 1 (the list contains 7 items in total)

Is there any possibility for this method to get called AGAIN without notifying that the datasat has changed?

Im a bit confused.

Kind Regards, 
Palm

Comment: What do you mean the same item?  If the item is the ViewHolder, then yes that is the way the recycler works. If you mean one entry from your data set then that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Sam 
By 'item' i mean one ViewHolder. 
So you say, this is the normal behavior of the RecyclerView.
I dont get the point, why it is called again, if the viewHolder was already created for this item without a change to the dataset?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly normal for a `RecyclerView` to call `onBindViewHolder()` multiple times.

A `RecyclerView` only creates minimum number of `Views` needed to fill the screen. And it works by reusing the old/created `Views`. So that when you are scrolling down the View that hid during the scrolling to the top is removed and brought next to the last visible `View` and added there. But since the `View` is currently bound with old data `onBindViewHolder()` is called again to ensure that the `View` is bound with only the correct data before it is rendered.

Similarly you'll notice that `onCreateViewHolder()` is only called the exact minimum number of `Views` it needs.

For a better understanding of how the `RecyclerView` works I suggest you read up on Recycler, LayoutManager and Recycler.Adapter the three core parts of a `RecyclerView`.